# Invoking TeamCity(TC) builds with multiple VCS roots through scripts

Tags: git, teamcity

I have a build which is on TeamCity(TC) server ‘A’ and is setup with 3 VCS Git roots. Branch specification of these roots includes ‘master’ and ‘Integration’ branches. When a change is detected on an integration branch (e.g Int_123), as a part of build step it gets rebased and then through scripts invokes builds on TC server ’B’ and ‘C’ which are also polling the same VCS roots.

‘A’ needs to pass this branch information to ‘B’ and ‘C’. Apart from branch name what other git information should it pass so that ‘B’ and ‘C’ pick up the right VCS root since the branchName(Int_123) may not be unique among the roots.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a snapshot dependency, that builds from the same chain, between the build configurations will keep your sources deeply connected. So when branch int_123 from VCS 1 is the source for the agent on server A. It will also be the source pulled from VCS 1 on the agent from server 2. This is because the revision number is used to determine the source, which is not only root specific, but "point in time" as well.